# How do I put Windows 11 on an HP ProBook 4530s with an unsupported CPU, no TPM and no secure boot?

Tags: laptop, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I am trying to install Windows 11 on my ProBook 4530s however, nothing I try will work. here are some things I have tried:

1. Using regedit to add the following keys:

> BypassRAMCheck set to 1

> BypassTPMCheck set to 1

> BypassSecureBootCheck set to 1

> AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU set to 1 (this was already present and already had the value 1)

2. Using the installation assistant, this simply says the computer isn't compatible and only gives me the option to exit.
3. Signing up for the insider program and attempting to update.
4. After using the health checker app it still gives errors for TPM, CPU and secure boot.

Is there a way that I can maybe create a patched .iso that will ignore the requirements? Is there a module that I can physically put in the laptop?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: somthing else i would like to add: i believe that secure boot is a software thing that must be enabled in bios. i have tried enabling `uefi boot` but that changes nothing.

Comment: Your laptop is just not up to the bare minimum standards, so I am confident in saying it will not run Windows 11.

Comment: The registry keys will only work if you perform a clean install (i.e. if you boot from an installation media created from the ISO), but __NOT__ if you perform an in-place upgrade by running `setup.exe`. You'll need to create a media that bypasses the Windows 11 requirements, using a utility like Rufus and __boot__ from that media.

Comment: I'm going to try creating a boot usb using a 3rd party program that patches the iso then if that dosent work I have a few more things to try

Answer (score 3):

> what are the chances that these requirements will be lowered in the future?

Microsoft will absolutely NOT change the system requirements for Windows 11 to support your hardware. The system requirements might be updated to support newer CPUs and/or newer revisions of TPM once they are released.

Your hardware is NOT compatible with Windows 11. Any method to install Windows 11 will require using **AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU** to bypass those system requirement. If your system doesn’t have enough memory then neither the reference script nor Rufus can create a compatible ISO for your machine.

> Is there a module that I can physically put in the laptop?

Your hardware cannot be upgraded to support Windows 11.

> Is there a way that I can maybe create a patched .iso that will ignore the requirements?

The current version of Rufus will create a patched ISO, however, it cannot be used to upgrade your current installation. There is also [this](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) script that do a similar function. All modern Intel and AMD CPUs support fTPM and Secure Boot, however, not all motherboards support it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it on several PC's [using rufus beta version.](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/10/11/disable-tpm-secure-boot-and-ram-requirements-for-windows-11/)

You can only do a clean install though.

It looks like rufus pulled the beta version [from their website](https://rufus.ie/downloads/), but I am sure you can find it elsewhere. I used rufus-3.16_BETA2

Comment: The reason why the BETA was pulled is because there have been two releases since then that include all the features from 3.16-BETA2. You __DON'T__ need to use the BETA any more. Just pick the latest release.

Comment: I tried that 2 weeks ago, they had later releases but they didnt include the W11 bypass feature.

Comment: Just tried 3.17, no option to modify W11 image.

Comment: It's definitely there. We didn't change the way you select the Windows 11 bypass between 3.16 BETA and 3.17. Just look under _Image options_. Other Rufus users seem to have no issue using the Windows 11 bypass with Rufus 3.17...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not possible with so many critical factors missing.  You need UEFI, GPT disk and Secure Boot at least. Your machine will not be able to be altered or configured to run Windows 11.

I have an older laptop with UEFI, Secure Boot and TPM1.2 and an unsupported processor and it is running Windows 11 Insider.

Try joining the Insider Program (Windows Update) and see if you can get Windows 11 that way to take a look.

Otherwise, Windows 10 is good until mid-2025 so that allows lots of time to consider things.

Comment: i have signed up for the insider program but the updater says it isnt compatable

Comment: So at this point, you will need a newer laptop.

Comment: that is somthing i am avoiding at all costs, maybe there is a patched iso that i can use?

Comment: I have been using Windows 11 for about 6 months and I have not seen that.

Comment: what are the chances that these requirements will be lowered in the future?

Comment: what are the chances that these requirements will be lowered in the future?   ....  Just about none at this point. I have an X1 with TPM2, UEFi, Secure boot and a CPU 1 year older than minimum and there does not appear to be any hope for it.

Comment: @verumIgnis - That’s because the system requirements for Windows 11 are enforced for Insider Preview builds.