# How to find out what’s preventing Windows 11 clean installation

Tags: windows-11

I’m trying to install Windows 11 on a brand new, today assembled computer. I just updated the bios on the Asus Prime B450-plus motherboard, which should support Windows 11.

The installation program starts ok from a usb stick but after entering the product key it just says that this computer doesn’t support Windows 11.

I’ve checked that AMD fTPM switch is enabled and that secure boot setting is Other OS.

How can I find out what’s causing this?

Comment: What's the CPU? W11 requires a Zen+ CPU at the least, first-generation Zen isn't accepted.

Comment: Run WhynotWin11.exe from Git Hub.  That will tell you.

Comment: The processor is a Ryzen 3600 that also seems to be supported. Can you tell me how to run WhynotWib11 from a bootable usb or similar?

Comment: Here is the download: https://www.whynotwin11.com/  ... You would need to make a bootable USB with Rufus. I have not tried running this from a USB - I have always run it from a working machine.

Comment: See my answer here for a workaround>>>https://superuser.com/a/1695917/40928

Comment: WhynotWin11 cannot be ran from a bootable environment on a flash drive, you need a working Windows install, in order to run it. “ secure boot setting is Other OS.” - Why are you selecting this option? Are you dual booting or something?

Comment: My suggestion would be to install Windows 10, then run the script I suggested in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1695904/how-do-i-put-windows-11-on-an-hp-probook-4530s-with-an-unsupported-cpu-no-tpm-a/1695911#1695911), to create a Windows 11 ISO and upgrade your installation to Windows 11.

Comment: I ended up installing Windows 10, running the script and then doing a clean install of Windows 11