# Asus (Hero VIII) BIOS TPM stopped working

Tags: bios, tpm, asus

I have installed windows 10 on this PC a few times and upgraded to windows 11 once but now its not seeing the TPM settings

[image]

[image]

System Info
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the entire output of MSInfo32? My suggestion would be just to enable [AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1695904/how-do-i-put-windows-11-on-an-hp-probook-4530s-with-an-unsupported-cpu-no-tpm-a/1695911#1695911) and upgrade regardless of the TPM status

Comment: @Ramhound i added sys info

Comment: This is useful for trouble shooting "Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected" https://superuser.com/questions/1345848/un-allowed-dma-capable-bus-devices-detected

Comment: Was that relevant to enabling TPM support on your device?